# Add commit number with gitlab CI Webhook

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is it possible to invalidate stylesheets with the gitlab CI Webhook?

I'd like to add the commit number as a url param onto the stylesheet link. Ist this possible? And if so, how?

```
<link href="/bla/styles.css?v=<!– gitlab deployment nr –>">
```

I really don't know much about gitlab demployment. I use a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file which does this:

```
production_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
  - LIVE
  environment:
    name: production
    url: domain.com
  variables:
    REMOTE_USER: "xyz"
    REMOTE_HOST: "domain.com"
```

And a `.gitlab-cd.sh` file which runs npm builds and syncs some folders (or at least that's what I think it does):

```
# sync
PATH_WWW_ROOT="xyz/"
PATH_WWW_ASSETS="xyz/theme/"

# Build assets if not cached.
npm run build
```

Is it possible to trigger this in the `.gitlab-cd.sh`?

I then hit "Merge Request" on the gitlab webgui and off it goes.

Comment: It would be easier if you told us how you're doing the deployment.

Comment: @JakubKania Does that help?